# Iterating over objects that may remove themselves from container

Tags: c++, iteration, containers, observer-pattern

How can I safely iterate over a container when the objects may be removed during iteration? I am basically trying to implement the observer pattern, and some events will cause listeners to be removed from the subscription container, which causes issues with iterators.

I considered the option of giving every listener a flag that it could set when it wish to be removed from the list of subscribers. So instead of the listener directly removing itself, the subject would check the flag during iteration, skip flagged listeners, and erase all flagged listeners after finished sending the notification.

The other option I considered was to launch a thread for every call to `listener.notify` and have the `remove_listener` method on the subject be a mutex locked operation.

The first option seems bad because the use of flags to indicate the status of some object tends to proliferate throughout a program and soon every time the object is handled it needs to be checked for `if (!object.TO_BE_DELETED)` similar to the problems stemming from null pointers.

The second option brings in all the hassle of using threads, and if the program uses a lot of events I'm pretty sure this will create performance issues quite quickly.

So what is a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without iterators:

```
for(int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(shouldDelete(v[i]))
        v.erase(v.begin() + i);
}
```

With iterators:

```
for(auto iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ) {
    if(shouldDelete(*iter)) {
        iter = v.erase(iter);
    } else iter++;
}
```

You can't use a range-for loop in this context, as deleting an element invalidates all iterators and the range-for loop uses iterators internally.

Note that I'm assuming vectors here; if you're using a list or set, only the iterator approach will work. (Both approaches should work for a deque.)

Answer (score 2):

you should never use the same iterator after erasing an element from a container because the iterator will loose sense you should have an updated version of the iterator . for example std::list::erase function return an iterator pointing to the next position of the removed element.